# Call timer using button

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

i have created a timer that is updated every one second

```
using System.Windows.Threading;

 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _dt_tick.Tick += new EventHandler(_dt_Tick);
        _dt_tick.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        _dt_tick.Start();
    }
```

after that i have creat a function linked to this timer

```
    private void _dt_Tick(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        ......


        }
        catch (Exception _ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(_ex.ToString(), "Error in Timer", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error); }
    }
```

what i want is to restart this timer once i have clicked in one button

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      ...........
    }
```

i have tried with _dt_Tick(object s, EventArgs e)  but it does not work

any idea please.its really urgent.

Comment: What do you meant by restart the timer? It will be already running right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the `stop` and `Start` methods?:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _dt_tick.Stop();
    _dt_tick.Start();
}
```

---

UPDATE>>>

Ah, your question was unclear, but now I see what you want. However, it is bad practice to call an event handler manually. Instead of this, add a new method that is called from your event handler. Then you can call that method from anywhere else as well:

```
private void _dt_Tick(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething();
}

private void DoSomething()
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception _ex)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show(_ex.ToString(), "Error in Timer", MessageBoxButton.OK, 
            MessageBoxImage.Error); 
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `_dt_tick` is a Timer object, why not use the following code in your `button1_Click` ?

```
_dt_tick.Stop();
_dt_tick.Start();
```

Comment: I don't use Timers much because they're typically not thread safe so do you have to reset the timer? _dt_tick.Reset(); Or something? Or do you have to dispose and recreate it every time you want to start over?

Comment: @Stefan it does not work, what i want is to call thisfunction private void _dt_Tick(object s, EventArgs e) in my button click event

Comment: @DaniPedrossa Your question is really unclear on that point, then. You can call it with `_dt_Tick(sender, new EventArgs())`.

Comment: @ Brandon J  i want to recreat it every time i start it over

Comment: @DaniPedrossa well that's not exactly what you asked, you asked how to reset a timer. :) You could use Chris' way to call _dt_Tick .

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as answered. I'm not sure if my answer is the one you should mark as the answer, as @ChrisMantle actually provided the answer.